# Ruby on rails rake db:create already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a database using:

```
rake db:create
```

That output a error: **db already exists**.

When I do a

```
rake db:drop
```

The output error is: **db does not exist**.

I have use external to connect to the DB server and indeed the DB does not exist.

Any help is much appreciated.